How to Detect Mouse Events like Left, Right Clicks, Scrolling and Taps in Compose Multiplatform?
I'm working on a Compose Multiplatform project (wasm only) where I need to detect left and right mouse clicks, as well as simple taps through the notebook's mousepad. I am using the following function within a Column:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Button(onClick = {
                        //navigator.push(Registration)
                     },
        modifier = Modifier
            .onKeyEvent { event ->
                list.add(0,"Unicode ${event.utf16CodePoint}")
                true
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                awaitPointerEventScope {
                    while (true) {
                        val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                        val position = event.changes.first().position

                        if(event.type == PointerEventType.Press) {
                            //navigator.push(Registration)
                        }
                        if (event.type != PointerEventType.Move) {
                            list.add(0, "${event.type} $position")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    ) {
        Text("Click me")
    }
}

This code registers taps as PointerEventType.Press, and it registers both right and left clicks as PointerEventType.Press followed by PointerEventType.Release.
For right clicking I get Unicode Mouse Right on the onKeyEvent but I cant get the other mouse events.
I need a way to distinguish between left clicks, right clicks, and simple taps more precisely and im pretty sure I will need all the Mouse Events at some point. How can I achieve this in Compose Multiplatform?

Tap: A quick touch on the notebook's mousepad using a finger.
Left Click: Pressing down and then releasing the mousepad with a finger.
Right Click: Pressing down and then releasing the right side of the mousepad with a finger.
Scrolling
Dragging

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

There is a function PointerInputScope.detectTapGestures in androidx.compose.foundation.gestures which might be useful. It has two overloads, one is:
public suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectTapGestures(
    onDoubleTap: ((Offset) -> Unit)? = null,
    onLongPress: ((Offset) -> Unit)? = null,
    onPress: suspend PressGestureScope.(Offset) -> Unit = NoPressGesture,
    onTap: ((Offset) -> Unit)? = null
): Unit

the other one is:
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
public suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectTapGestures(
    matcher: PointerMatcher = PointerMatcher.Primary,
    keyboardModifiers: PointerKeyboardModifiers.() -> Boolean = { true },
    onDoubleTap: ((Offset) -> Unit)? = null,
    onLongPress: ((Offset) -> Unit)? = null,
    onPress: suspend PressGestureScope.(Offset) -> Unit = { },
    onTap: ((Offset) -> Unit)? = null
): Unit

If you pass matcher as PointerMatcher.Secondary, you get all the functions for right click of the mouse.
here is the link
